# How would I add an image to a quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

How would I make an image to appear when the quiz tells you the correct answer after you have submitted which option you think is correct , then disappear when it goes to the next question? Ideally would want the image to appear beside the quiz.
If anyone knows that would be great.
cheers

The current code is as follows:

**HTML**:

```
<body onload="NextQuestion(0)">
    <main>
        <!-- creating a modal for when quiz ends -->
        <div class="modal-container" id="score-modal">

            <div class="modal-content-container">

                <h1>Congratulations, Quiz Completed.</h1>

                <div class="grade-details">
                    <p>Attempts : 10</p>
                    <p>Wrong Answers : <span id="wrong-answers"></span></p>
                    <p>Right Answers : <span id="right-answers"></span></p>
                    <p>Grade : <span id="grade-percentage"></span>%</p>
                    <p ><span id="remarks"></span></p>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-button-container">
                    <button onclick="closeScoreModal()">Continue</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
<!-- end of modal of quiz details-->

        <div class="game-quiz-container">

            <div class="game-details-container">
                <h1>Score : <span id="player-score"></span> / 10</h1>
                <h1> Question : <span id="question-number"></span> / 10</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="game-question-container">
                <h1 id="display-question"></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="game-options-container">

               <div class="modal-container" id="option-modal">

                    <div class="modal-content-container">
                         <h1>Please Pick An Option</h1>

                         <div class="modal-button-container">
                            <button onclick="closeOptionModal()">Continue</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

               </div>

                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="option" class="radio" value="optionA" />
                    <label for="option-one" class="option" id="option-one-label"></label>
                </span>


                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-two" name="option" class="radio" value="optionB" />
                    <label for="option-two" class="option" id="option-two-label"></label>
                </span>


                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-three" name="option" class="radio" value="optionC" />
                    <label for="option-three" class="option" id="option-three-label"></label>
                </span>


                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-four" name="option" class="radio" value="optionD" />
                    <label for="option-four" class="option" id="option-four-label"></label>
                </span>


            </div>

            <div class="next-button-container">
                <button onclick="handleNextQuestion()">Next Question</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**javascript**:

```
let shuffledQuestions = [] //empty array to hold shuffled selected questions out of all available questions

function handleQuestions() { 
    //function to shuffle and push 10 questions to shuffledQuestions array
//app would be dealing with 10questions per session
    while (shuffledQuestions.length <= 9) {
        const random = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)]
        if (!shuffledQuestions.includes(random)) {
            shuffledQuestions.push(random)
        }
    }
}


let questionNumber = 1 //holds the current question number
let playerScore = 0  //holds the player score
let wrongAttempt = 0 //amount of wrong answers picked by player
let indexNumber = 0 //will be used in displaying next question

// function for displaying next question in the array to dom
//also handles displaying players and quiz information to dom
function NextQuestion(index) {
    handleQuestions()
    const currentQuestion = shuffledQuestions[index]
    document.getElementById("question-number").innerHTML = questionNumber
    document.getElementById("player-score").innerHTML = playerScore
    document.getElementById("display-question").innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;
    document.getElementById("option-one-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionA;
    document.getElementById("option-two-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionB;
    document.getElementById("option-three-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionC;
    document.getElementById("option-four-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionD;

}


function checkForAnswer() {
    const currentQuestion = shuffledQuestions[indexNumber] //gets current Question 
    const currentQuestionAnswer = currentQuestion.correctOption //gets current Question's answer
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option"); //gets all elements in dom with name of 'option' (in this the radio inputs)
    let correctOption = null

    options.forEach((option) => {
        if (option.value === currentQuestionAnswer) {
            //get's correct's radio input with correct answer
            correctOption = option.labels[0].id
        }
    })

    //checking to make sure a radio input has been checked or an option being chosen
    if (options[0].checked === false && options[1].checked === false && options[2].checked === false && options[3].checked == false) {
        document.getElementById('option-modal').style.display = "flex"
    }

    //checking if checked radio button is same as answer
    options.forEach((option) => {
        if (option.checked === true && option.value === currentQuestionAnswer) {
            document.getElementById(correctOption).style.backgroundColor = "green"
            playerScore++ //adding to player's score
            indexNumber++ //adding 1 to index so has to display next question..
            //set to delay question number till when next question loads
            setTimeout(() => {
                questionNumber++
            }, 1000)
        }

        else if (option.checked && option.value !== currentQuestionAnswer) {
            const wrongLabelId = option.labels[0].id
            document.getElementById(wrongLabelId).style.backgroundColor = "red"
            document.getElementById(correctOption).style.backgroundColor = "green"
            wrongAttempt++ //adds 1 to wrong attempts 
            indexNumber++
            //set to delay question number till when next question loads
            setTimeout(() => {
                questionNumber++
            }, 1000)
        }
    })
}



//called when the next button is called
function handleNextQuestion() {
    checkForAnswer() //check if player picked right or wrong option
    unCheckRadioButtons()
    //delays next question displaying for a second just for some effects so questions don't rush in on player
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (indexNumber <= 9) {
//displays next question as long as index number isn't greater than 9, remember index number starts from 0, so index 9 is question 10
            NextQuestion(indexNumber)
        }
        else {
            handleEndGame()//ends game if index number greater than 9 meaning we're already at the 10th question
        }
        resetOptionBackground()
    }, 1000);
}

//sets options background back to null after display the right/wrong colors
function resetOptionBackground() {
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option");
    options.forEach((option) => {
        document.getElementById(option.labels[0].id).style.backgroundColor = ""
    })
}

// unchecking all radio buttons for next question(can be done with map or foreach loop also)
function unCheckRadioButtons() {
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option");
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        options[i].checked = false;
    }
}

// function for when all questions being answered
function handleEndGame() {
    let remark = null
    let remarkColor = null

    // condition check for player remark and remark color
    if (playerScore <= 3) {
        remark = "Bad Grades, Keep Practicing."
        remarkColor = "red"
    }
    else if (playerScore >= 4 && playerScore < 7) {
        remark = "Average Grades, You can do better."
        remarkColor = "orange"
    }
    else if (playerScore >= 7) {
        remark = "Excellent, Keep the good work going."
        remarkColor = "green"
    }
    const playerGrade = (playerScore / 10) * 100

    //data to display to score board
    document.getElementById('remarks').innerHTML = remark
    document.getElementById('remarks').style.color = remarkColor
    document.getElementById('grade-percentage').innerHTML = playerGrade
    document.getElementById('wrong-answers').innerHTML = wrongAttempt
    document.getElementById('right-answers').innerHTML = playerScore
    document.getElementById('score-modal').style.display = "flex"

}

//closes score modal, resets game and reshuffles questions
function closeScoreModal() {
    questionNumber = 1
    playerScore = 0
    wrongAttempt = 0
    indexNumber = 0
    shuffledQuestions = []
    NextQuestion(indexNumber)
    document.getElementById('score-modal').style.display = "none"
}

//function to close warning modal
function closeOptionModal() {
    document.getElementById('option-modal').style.display = "none"
}
```

Comment: should the image show only if the correct answer is chosen?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. No it doesn't matter if the answer is right or wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In my approach, some JavaScript has been used in order to figure out the splash timeout. It comes up, once the 'Next Question' is clicked.

`.imgForCorrAnswer` and `.hidden` are the CSS classes here, in fact, there was no stylesheet in the original code. `@keyframes` added along with few JS lines, so the splash image will only be displayed for 2 seconds or how much you assign into its CSS class: `--timeout` and JS variable: `timeout`

Furthermore, `href` is added surrounding Next Question button element, so page will be scrolled down to `#splashDiv` but as the splash image disappears, space occupied by its size will also be released. You may use a lightweight image here, so it won't take long for loading.

These sources were helpful when working on this,
[Why the Need to Animate “display”? - ImpressiveWebs](https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/)
[CSS Animations - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)
[CSS Variables - MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)

```js
let shuffledQuestions = [] //empty array to hold shuffled selected questions out of all available questions

function handleQuestions() { 
    //function to shuffle and push 10 questions to shuffledQuestions array
//app would be dealing with 10questions per session
    while (shuffledQuestions.length <= 9) {
        const random = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)]
        if (!shuffledQuestions.includes(random)) {
            shuffledQuestions.push(random)
        }
    }
}

let questionNumber = 1 //holds the current question number
let playerScore = 0  //holds the player score
let wrongAttempt = 0 //amount of wrong answers picked by player
let indexNumber = 0 //will be used in displaying next question

// function for displaying next question in the array to dom
//also handles displaying players and quiz information to dom
function NextQuestion(index) {
    handleQuestions()
    const currentQuestion = shuffledQuestions[index];
    document.getElementById("question-number").innerHTML = questionNumber
    document.getElementById("player-score").innerHTML = playerScore
    document.getElementById("display-question").innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;
    document.getElementById("option-one-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionA;
    document.getElementById("option-two-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionB;
    document.getElementById("option-three-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionC;
    document.getElementById("option-four-label").innerHTML = currentQuestion.optionD;
}

function checkForAnswer() {
    const currentQuestion = shuffledQuestions[indexNumber] //gets current Question 
    const currentQuestionAnswer = currentQuestion.correctOption //gets current Question's answer
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option"); //gets all elements in dom with name of 'option' (in this the radio inputs)
    let correctOption = null;

    options.forEach((option) => {
        if (option.value === currentQuestionAnswer) {
            //get's correct's radio input with correct answer
            correctOption = option.labels[0].id
        }
    })

    //checking to make sure a radio input has been checked or an option being chosend
    if (options[0].checked === false && options[1].checked === false && options[2].checked === false && options[3].checked == false) {
        document.getElementById('option-modal').style.display = "flex"
    }

    //checking if checked radio button is same as answer
    options.forEach((option) => {
        if (option.checked === true && option.value === currentQuestionAnswer) {
            document.getElementById(correctOption).style.backgroundColor = "green"
            playerScore++ //adding to player's score
            indexNumber++ //adding 1 to index so has to display next question..
            //set to delay question number till when next question loads
            setTimeout(() => {
                questionNumber++
            }, 1000)
        }

        else if (option.checked && option.value !== currentQuestionAnswer) {
            const wrongLabelId = option.labels[0].id
            document.getElementById(wrongLabelId).style.backgroundColor = "red"
            document.getElementById(correctOption).style.backgroundColor = "green"
            wrongAttempt++ //adds 1 to wrong attempts 
            indexNumber++
            //set to delay question number till when next question loads
            setTimeout(() => {
                questionNumber++
            }, 1000)
        }
    })
}



//called when the next button is called
function handleNextQuestion() {
   document.getElementById("splashDiv")
   
  // assign 'splashDiv' to a JS variable
  let img = document.getElementById("splashDiv");
  
  // add CSS class 'splashImgCl'
  img.classList.add("splashImgCl");
  
  // adjust this timeout along with CSS --timeout
  let timeout = 4000;
  
  // timeout function corresponding to CSS '--timeout'
  setTimeout(()=>{
    img.classList.add("hidden");
  },timeout);
     img.classList.remove("hidden");
     img.classList.add("imgForCorrAnswer");
    checkForAnswer() //check if player picked right or wrong option
    unCheckRadioButtons()
    //delays next question displaying for a second just for some effects so questions don't rush in on player
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (indexNumber <= 9) {
//displays next question as long as index number isn't greater than 9, remember index number starts from 0, so index 9 is question 10
            NextQuestion(indexNumber)
        }
        else {
            handleEndGame()//ends game if index number greater than 9 meaning we're already at the 10th question
        }
        resetOptionBackground()
    }, 1000);
  
 
}

//sets options background back to null after display the right/wrong colors
function resetOptionBackground() {
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option");
    options.forEach((option) => {
        document.getElementById(option.labels[0].id).style.backgroundColor = ""
    })
}

// unchecking all radio buttons for next question(can be done with map or foreach loop also)
function unCheckRadioButtons() {
    const options = document.getElementsByName("option");
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        options[i].checked = false;
    }
}

// function for when all questions being answered
function handleEndGame() {
    let remark = null
    let remarkColor = null

    // condition check for player remark and remark color
    if (playerScore <= 3) {
        remark = "Bad Grades, Keep Practicing."
        remarkColor = "red"
    }
    else if (playerScore >= 4 && playerScore < 7) {
        remark = "Average Grades, You can do better."
        remarkColor = "orange"
    }
    else if (playerScore >= 7) {
        remark = "Excellent, Keep the good work going."
        remarkColor = "green"
    }
    const playerGrade = (playerScore / 10) * 100

    //data to display to score board
    document.getElementById('remarks').innerHTML = remark
    document.getElementById('remarks').style.color = remarkColor
    document.getElementById('grade-percentage').innerHTML = playerGrade
    document.getElementById('wrong-answers').innerHTML = wrongAttempt
    document.getElementById('right-answers').innerHTML = playerScore
    document.getElementById('score-modal').style.display = "flex"

}

//closes score modal, resets game and reshuffles questions
function closeScoreModal() {
    questionNumber = 1
    playerScore = 0
    wrongAttempt = 0
    indexNumber = 0
    shuffledQuestions = []
    NextQuestion(indexNumber)
    document.getElementById('score-modal').style.display = "none"
}

//function to close warning modal
function closeOptionModal() {
    document.getElementById('option-modal').style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
/* adjust this CSS variable along with JS timeout */
:root{
  --timeout: 4s;
}

.splashImgCl{
  margin: .9rem auto 0 0;
  border-radius: 10%;
  max-width: 10px;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/Kingella_kingae_PHIL12451.jpg/330px-Kingella_kingae_PHIL12451.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  padding: max(17%);
  animation-name: imgForCorrAnswer-anim;
  animation-duration: var(--timeout);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes imgForCorrAnswer-anim{
    0%{opacity: 100%;}
    100%{opacity: 0%; } 
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="NextQuestion(0)">
    <main>
    
        <!-- creating a modal for when quiz ends -->
        <div class="modal-container" id="score-modal">

            <div class="modal-content-container">

                <h1>Congratulations, Quiz Completed.</h1>

                <div class="grade-details">
                    <p>Attempts : 10</p>
                    <p>Wrong Answers : <span id="wrong-answers"></span></p>
                    <p>Right Answers : <span id="right-answers"></span></p>
                    <p>Grade : <span id="grade-percentage"></span>%</p>
                    <p ><span id="remarks"></span></p>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-button-container">
                    <button onclick="closeScoreModal()">Continue</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
<!-- end of modal of quiz details-->

        <div class="game-quiz-container">

            <div class="game-details-container">
                <h1>Score : <span id="player-score"></span> / 10</h1>
                <h1> Question : <span id="question-number"></span> / 10</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="game-question-container">
                <h1 id="display-question"></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="game-options-container">

               <div class="modal-container" id="option-modal">

                    <div class="modal-content-container">
                         <h1>Please Pick An Option</h1>

                         <div class="modal-button-container">
                            <button onclick="closeOptionModal()">Continue</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

               </div>

                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="option" class="radio" value="optionA" />
                    <label for="option-one" class="option" id="option-one-label"></label>
                </span>


                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-two" name="option" class="radio" value="optionB" />
                    <label for="option-two" class="option" id="option-two-label"></label>
                </span>


                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-three" name="option" class="radio" value="optionC" />
                    <label for="option-three" class="option" id="option-three-label"></label>
                </span>


                <span>
                    <input type="radio" id="option-four" name="option" class="radio" value="optionD" />
                    <label for="option-four" class="option" id="option-four-label"></label>
                </span>


            </div>

            <a href="#splashDiv"><div class="next-button-container">
                <button onclick="handleNextQuestion()">Next Question</button>
            </div></a>

        </div>
        
          <!--- splash image div --->
        <div id="splashDiv"></div>
      <!--- end of splah image div --->
    </main>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```